# Why is not correct the way I'm using my dynamic array of strings?

Tags: c, string, pointers, dynamic

I've a `.log` file. In this file there are many lines. All I want to do is to read each single line and put it into a dynamic array of string:

```
   char **all_samples = malloc(sizeof(char));

    int i=0; 

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1)
    {
        if (strstr(line, slave) != NULL)
        {
            all_samples[i] = malloc(sizeof(*line)*len+1);
            all_samples[i] = line;
            line = NULL;
            i++;

        }

    }
```

What happens is that the array only contains about 20 strings, and after this number I have a segmentation fault. Thanks to the `i` index, I know that the number of strings the array should contain is 32. What am I doing wrong? The error is in the memory allocation? Where is the problem? Can you please explaine me also theorically what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `char **all_samples = malloc(sizeof(char));`, no you're messing up the types. It should be `char **all_samples = malloc(sizeof(**all_samples));`

Comment: @SouravGhosh `sizeof(**all_samples)` is as wrong as `sizeof(char)`. Both equal to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See how you go with this:
(No responsibility taken for unseen code.)

```
#define MAX_SLAVES (32)

// Get a pointer to heap array of 32 pointers to char (ie: strings)
// calloc() used because region is init'd to 0's
char **all_samples = calloc( MAX_SLAVES, sizeof *all_samples );
/* omitting test for NULL */

int i=0; 

// No experience with 'getline()'. 'fgets()' would be portable
while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1)
{
    if (strstr(line, slave) != NULL && i < MAX_SLAVES ) // VERY important!
    {
        all_samples[i] = malloc( strlen( line ) + 1 );
        /* omitting test for NULL */

        strcpy( all_samples[i], line );
        i++;
        // line = NULL; // is this necessary???
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is that before I read the file, I can't know how many lines I will go to save into the array. So, how can I correctly allocate memori for **all_samples?

Comment: If quantity is unknown, then you could be overly generous. These days, memory is measured in Gb... Otherwise, you could change to use a "linked list" instead of an array, only adding entries when necessary... Or, there's `realloc()` to grow an array, but coding that is a tiny bit more difficult. If you can, I'd suggest going with a linked list solution. They're straight forward and extensible. There are LOTS of linked list questions and answers here on SO... Try searching for some...

Comment: I guess the `line = NULL;` is to tell `getline` to allocate more memory at the next string input. OP is storing a pointer to that memory, and the `malloc` was just a memory leak.